# css rotate text vertically across table columns

Tags: html, css

I have a matrix which, because of the subjects names, is stretching off screen
I wish to create a training matrix with the abilities on the left, colored cells for the acquired skill, with the subjects name vertically across the columns. [image]

I have tries using bootstrap and css rules to rotate text, but I cant get the text to float above the grid

apologies, this is what I have tried :

```
  <style>
   .rotate {

    transform: rotate(90deg);
    width: 8rem;
    }
  </style>

  </head>
  <body>


  <div class="row">

  <div class="col">

  <table class="table">
  <tr> <td> </td>
  <tr> <td> <p class="text-nowrap bd-highlight rotate ">Bruce Wayne.  </p> </td>

  <tr> <td> <p class="text-nowrap bd-highlight rotate ">Clark Kent.</p> </td>

  <tr> <td> <p class="text-nowrap bd-highlight rotate ">Barry Allen.</p> </td>
  </tr>


<tr> <td> Detective</td>   <td class="table-success"> </td> <td class="table-success"></td> <td class="table-success"></td> </tr>
<tr> <td> can fly</td>   <td class="table-success"> </td> <td class="table-success"></td> <td class="table-success"></td> </tr>
<tr> <td> runs fast</td> <td class="table-success"> </td> <td class="table-success"></td> <td class="table-success"></td> </tr>
<tr> <td> plays well</td>  <td class="table-success"> </td> <td class="table-success"></td>  </tr>


  </table>
```

all the vertical text stacks to the left of the screen.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/rotated-table-column-headers/

Comment: are you looking to achieve something exactly like the image you posted?

Comment: yes.  I have made a css rule that looks okay - ish.     .rotate {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform-origin: 10% 70% ;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    width: 8rem;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```css
.table {
  background: grey;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  border: none;
  width: 500px;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 8rem;
}

td {
  width: 25%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.vertical {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 200%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.
```

```html
<body>


  <div class="row">

    <div class="col">

      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td> Detective</td>
          <td class="table-success"><span class="vertical"> Bruce Wayne</span> </td>
          <td class="table-success"><span class="vertical"> clark Kent</span></td>
          <td class="table-success"><span class="vertical"> barry allen</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> can fly</td>
          <td class="table-success"> </td>
          <td class="table-success"></td>
          <td class="table-success"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> runs fast</td>
          <td class="table-success"> </td>
          <td class="table-success"></td>
          <td class="table-success"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> plays well</td>
          <td class="table-success"> </td>
          <td class="table-success"></td>
          <td class="table-success"></td>
        </tr>


      </table>
```

Comment: What does `top: 200%` do?

Comment: this is what I had mangled :      .rotate {
      display: block;
      font-weight: bold;
      position: relative;
      white-space: nowrap;
      transform-origin: 10% 70% ;
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      width: 6rem;
      }

Comment: @SalmanA it sets the `top` edge of the `.vertical` span element `200%` of parent `td's` height down from the top edge of its relative parent. I used it to  align the `span` vertically (yet it is not centered) such a way it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given your code how you did it but I give you a solution. Hope this is useful for you.

```css
    .rotate{
          transform: rotate(-90deg);
      }
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
         <td class="rotate">BRUCE</td>
   <td class="rotate">CLARK</td>
   <td class="rotate">BARRY</td>
  </tr>
     </table>
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but the text does not float above the rows beneath the top row.  Also the first part of the text is truncated.  I have added the code i am working with.